# java String and StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am confuse about String and String Builder. Here is my simple code

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("123");
String s1 = "123";
sb1.append("abc"); 
s1.concat("abc");
System.out.println(sb1 + " " + s1);
```

**sb1** output for **123abc**. It is ok!  because it use append method.But String **s1** should be abc123
but it output is **abc**. Why? And what is concat method purpose? Please explain me.

Thank you

Comment: Strings are Immutable... Try reading String immutable concept

Comment: Your output for s1 is 123,but wrongly you  wrote as abc.  It confused me  :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> .But String s1 should be abc123 but it output is abc.

Strings are immutable in Java. `concat` doesn't change the *existing* string - it returns a *new* string. So if you use:

```
String result = s1.concat("abc");
```

then *that* will be "123abc" - but `s1` will still be "123". (Or rather, the value of `s1` will still be a reference to a string with contents "123".)

The same is true for any other methods on `String` which you *might* expect to change the contents, e.g. `replace` and `toLowerCase`. When you call a method on string but don't use the result (as is the case here), that's pretty much always a bug.

The fact that strings are immutable is the whole reason for `StringBuilder` existing in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understood. String are immutable. StringBuilder are mutable.

Answer (score 3):

concat function not change the string but it returns the result which is not assigned in your case:

```
String concat(String textToAppend)
```

so change:

```
s1 = s1.concat("abc");
```

Answer (score 3):

string objects are immutable. Immutable simply means unmodifiable or unchangeable

but if you give

```
String result = s1.concat("abc");
```

output  is 123abc
and
`StringBuilder` are mutable
you can perform changes

Answer (score 1):

s1.concat("abc") will create a new object in heap with the "abc" concatenated to s1. but s1 is still pointing to original s1 which is "123". so you need to make your s1 reference to point to new object using s1 = s1.concat("abc");